# Ignite cache transactioin and putAsync

Tags: java, ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite Cache with transactions. Currently I use regular cache.put() methods but wonder if I should better use recommended putAsync()? If using the async methods, does Transaction.commit() wait for all async puts to finish or do I have to do this in my code?

This would be my simplified code:

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();
IgniteTransactions transactions = ignite.transactions();
tx = transactions.txStart(TransactionConcurrency.PESSIMISTIC, TransactionIsolation.SERIALIZABLE, 10 * 1000, 0);

IgniteFuture fut = cache.putAsync("KEY", "VALUE");

fut.get(); // do I need to call this?

tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, commit() will wait for async methods to finish. Please note that you can only have one async method running at the same time - if you have one, the next one will run synchronously.